# How to store a set of string space efficiently

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Assume we have a set of string

```
{"abc","def","ghia"}
```

What is the space efficient way to store the string?
In addition, given an input string like "abc" or "abc1", I need find out whether `"abc"`(yes) or `"abc1"`(no) is in the list of string, and if it is not, add to the list of string.

Further suppose that we only have 26 lowercase alphabet for all the string, the length of string is 0 to infinite.

Comment: Your question seems to push to a solution that compresses common prefixes. But without any knowledge of the distribution of your strings, it's hard to give a useful answer. For instance, Huffman coding could be appropriate, but we cannot guess.

Comment: Actually I am not sure to understand your question. Is it about minimizing the storage space or allowing efficient searches ? Is the list of string known once for all or is it dynamic (allowing additions and even deletions ?)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Note however that a trie is more of a set than a list considering that the elements are unordered and (in a naive implementation) does not support duplicates.

Comment: thanks, a set would be sufficient, question modified

Comment: Did you find out if a trie was the right choice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your limitation. 
R-way trie is one of the fast way to retrieve stored data, also it supplies a way to determine whether the data is in the set or not, but R-way requires (R+1)N memory space, so 27N in your case ( N stands for the number of data, and R for the your character domain).

There are other types of trie which requires less memory, like as Ternary Search Trie. But it requires 4N space.
This is nothing better than OrderedDict, if the foot print of memory is the first concern.

Therefore, if you can't bear with using those like that, you can make your own data type, 5bits data type. 
Because 26 characters can be expressed with only 5 bits. 
For example, the ISO9959-1 encoding of "abc" is "0b01100001, 0b01100010, 0b01100011", 
but these can be 0b00001 00010 00011[0] ( 0 for padding).

```
nChars           1  2  3  4  5
8byte-rep        8 16 16 24 32
5bits-rep.       5 10 15 20 25    
actual-req       8 16 24 32 40
(with 8bits-packing)
diff(saving)     0  0  8  8  8
```